# Force a string number to be 2 decimal places

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to change a string with a number to be 2 decimal places?

#### Code that cannot be edited

```
mainR = pull1.group(0).title().replace(u"£", "PSO")
print mainR
```

#### Outputs:

```
Student: PSO250.00
```

#### Sometimes outputs:

```
Student: PSO250.000
```

#### Example print outputs:

```
Student: PSO250.000
StudentB: PSO323.42424242
ClassTotal: PSO10.0
Class: PSO1.00000000
```

#### Correct Outputs:

```
Student: PSO250.00
StudentB: PSO323.42
ClassTotal: PSO10.00
Class: PSO1.00
```

How can I change it so that it forces the string so that if it comes out at `250.000` the number would be changed/forced to be 2 decimal places?

Any ideas?

Comment: so your question is how to change the output without changing the code? That sounds like a tall order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string always has a decimal point:

```
print (mainR+'0')[:mainR.find('.')+3]
```

Comment: @falsetru, missed that.  Updated, but don't like it as much now :)

Answer (score 2):

Using capturing group:

```
>>> re.sub('(\.\d\d)\d+', r'\1', 'PSO250.000')
'PSO250.00'
>>> re.sub('(\.\d\d)\d+', r'\1', 'PSO250.00000')
'PSO250.00'
```

**UPDATE**

```
>>> output = '''Student: PSO250.000
... StudentB: PSO323.42424242
... ClassTotal: PSO10.0
... Class: PSO1.00000000'''

>>> print re.sub('(?<=\.)\d+', lambda m: m.group()[:2].ljust(2, '0'), output)
Student: PSO250.00
StudentB: PSO323.42
ClassTotal: PSO10.00
Class: PSO1.00
```

Comment: OP's call finally but this doesn't do the job on `PSO250.00000`

Comment: I need to preserve the student part (that's a name), basically the last "group" needs to be edited into 2dp, it could at first be an 8 dp number.

Comment: @Hyflex, I don't understand your coomment. Do you mean you want to get `250.00` out of `Student: PSO250.000`?

Comment: Edited original post for more details.

Comment: @falsetru I believe he wants to trim the entire mainR string down (or up) to 2 dp, which in his example is `mainR = "Student: PSO250.000"` or it could be `mainR = "TeacherBC: PSO250.0"` or leave it if `mainR = "Person: PSO250.00"`

Comment: @BeanBagKing, OP also want `ClassTotal: PSO10.0` to become `ClassTotal: PSO10.00`.